# How to change DHCP config?

Tags: dhcp

I am trying to access an ims core from the ims client in my Android device, however I need to modify the dhcp client to add the ip of the core as one of the DNS. In case of a Linux OS the following would do the job::

```
cd /etc/dhcp3/ ; vi dhclient.conf ; /* add the line:: prepend domain-name-servers 152.xx.xx.xx(ip of ims core) / sudo dhclient ; / to restart*/
```

Now the issue is how do I achieve the same in my Android?

Comment: Which Android device do you have? Version? Rooted / Unrooted?

Comment: I am having Motorola A855

Comment: If you want to set a DNS server for one/some access points, you can use [Wifi Static](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.statIc).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really address your DHCP question (not sure what sysprop that would be), but it will fix your DNS issues. You can make an ASE script for it if you don't want to have to do it every time your DNS is changed by the provider.

Also, depending on how your DNS server is setup you may want to change the INT at the end of line one to "2" or "3" and add some other DNS servers for the rest of the internet (openDNS, google DNS, etc).

Open an adb shell or Terminal Emulator and type:

```
setprop ro.kernel.android.ndns 1
setprop net.eth0.dns1 152.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Alternatively, just throw the server(s) you want to resolve into `/system/etc/hosts`, like you would in a normal linux system.

Comment: note that not all devices have `net.eth0.dns1`, some use `net.dns1` or `net.gprs0.dns1`, check this with getprop.

Answer (score 0):

On my device I got

```
/etc/dhcpd/dhclient.conf
```

To get a new IP from DHCP you can run

```
dhcpcd -k wlan0
dhcpcd -n wlan0
```

Comment: /system/bin/sh: cat: /etc/dhcpd/dhclient.conf: No such file or directory