# Configuring DHCP client on my Android board

Tags: 2.2-froyo, dhcp

I am running Android on my development board and want to configure DHCP client on it. Can anyone tell the details of what steps to be followed to configure DHCP client on Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/how-to-change-dhcp-config

Comment: This does not help. I have tried running dhclient on linux pc and it works fine there. But there is no dhclient for android what I have is dhcpcd. which fails always.

Answer (score -1):

enable the ethernet port and then use **setprop** command to enable dhcp. Then start dhcp client.

Comment: Could you [edit] and clarify which properties should be set to enable DHCP?